# how to pass the value to the viewModel from a multiple list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have two model list and master model. I need to access and store value to the model properties. not sure how to do this using a viewModel? previously I was using viewData list and now I wan to  test viewModel.

```html
<---Model--->
public class Master
 {
   public List<Table1> T1 { get; set; }
   public List<Table2> T2 { get; set; }
 }
 
public class Table1
{
  public string sample1 { get; set; }
  public string sample1 { get; set; }
}

public class Table2
{
  public string sample1 { get; set; }
  public string sample2 { get; set; }
}


<--Controller-->
Master master  = new Master();
var getSamples = _db.dbSamples.Where(y => y.sample == "xxxx");

foreach(var row in T1)  <<---- I need help correcting this part. I believe this is not right...
  {
    foreach (var item in getSamples)
      {
        row.sample1 = item.A;
        row.sample2 = item.B;
      }
   }
return View(master);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the question and please add an example of your needed output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public class Master
 {
   public List<Table1> T1 { get; set; }
   public List<Table2> T2 { get; set; }
 }
 
public class Table1
{
  public string sample1 { get; set; }
  public string sample2 { get; set; }
}

public class Table2
{
  public string sample1 { get; set; }
  public string sample2 { get; set; }
}

        <--Controller-->
        Master master  = new Master();
        var getSamples = _db.dbSamples.Where(y => y.sample == "sample1");
        var table1List = new List<Table1>();
        var table2List = new List<Table2>();
        var masterData= new Master();
            foreach (var item in getSamples)
              {
                var data = new Table1();
                data.A = item.A;
                data.B = item.B;
                table1List.add(data);
              }
        master.T1 = table1List;
        var getSamples1 = _db.dbSamples.Where(y => y.sample == "sample2");
           foreach (var item in getSamples1)
              {
                var data2 = new Table2();
                data2.A = item.A;
                data2.B = item.B;
                table2List.add(data2);
              }
        master.T2 = table2List;
        return View(master);
```

I assume that what you are trying to do is this. If it is not, please elaborate on the question.

Updated code. Change variable names accordingly.

Comment: Hello Reshma, I'm implementing similar to this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36892770/pass-multiple-list-from-multiple-models-to-view-from-controller

Comment: I updated the code above. apologies for the confusion Reshma

Comment: Please check the updated code. Still not sure about what data you need in the T2 list. I just added an example query for T2 list. Replace it with your actual query.

Comment: Hi Reshma, You got it right. my bad , var data = new Table1();  which is missing in my code so i dont have to do iterate in multiple foreach :)  thank you for  the effort making an example. . I was able to get the correct output now in my view. I really appeciate your help and support :)